# Having trouble with partition while dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.10, windows-7

So I have already made a partition of 100 GB in windows but when I loaded ubuntu 13.10 from a usb stick and tried installing it ubuntu didn't give me the option of installing along side windows. When I clicked something else and then clicked on 100 GB free disk space it still wouldn't let me. This is the first time for me to install a new OS so simple anwers would be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 GB partition created on Windows should not be an ext4 partition,so you can't install Ubuntu on it.

Try to format the 100 GB partition into ext4 filesystem.To do this,

- Boot the Ubuntu live disk.Select the try Ubuntu option on startup.
- Now open Gparted partition Editor from dash.
- Right click on the 100 GB partition and select "Format to" option to format it into ext4 filesystem.
- Now run the Ubuntu installer and then choose something else option.This time you can be able to install Ubuntu on that 100 GB partition.

**Note**:Make sure that the 100 GB partition is unmounted.